# Header changes according to the content of the activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm developing an application, and in the main activity I need the title to be visible until I pass the entire RecyclerView, the same idea as the image below. When the user scrolls the contacts saved on the phone, the initial letter of the contacts on the side changes and the current letter is displayed at the top. Another example is the conversation date of WhatsApp, which is exposed the day of the conversation, a blue label exposed at the top.

Example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwuWNQwEuP2HYzBRUUI3c3ljWFk/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: What have you done till this point? Please provide your code then ask what you are struggling with.

Comment: Sorry, i can't add the image

Comment: I didn't say anything about a image?

Comment: I will explain better

Comment: I posted an link to show what i need

Comment: Sorry but stack overflow doesn't work like that, post your code in the question, don't post a link to your code.I would advise you to first look at other questions and how they asked and you can read the - how to ask a question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, i will read but I still don't have code, because I don't know How to do